# Cannot add column and create user by built-in method

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to work with a database. I was recommended to use Gorm, however, it is annoying since some methods are not working.

For model I have:

```
type UserModel struct {
    first_name string
    last_name string
}
```

Here is my sample code and results of it.

The below code works but in my database the table name is `user_models`

```
 db.Migrator().CreateTable(&UserModel{})
```

The below code is not working

```
err := db.Migrator().AddColumn(&UserModel{}, "first_name")
```

> failed to look up field with name: first_name

I tried this instead and it works

```
db.Exec("ALTER TABLE user_models ADD first_name varchar(64);")
```

Another not working

```
user := UserModel{first_name: "Jinzhu", last_name: "name"}
```

> Not error but insert first_name:null and last_name:null

Finally, can any help me solve these problems?

Comment: Requests for library recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow, so I removed that part of your question while editing for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two fields "first_name" and "last_name" (both of which do not follow Go recommendations for naming) are unexported since they start with lowercase letters. This means Gorm does not pay attention to those fields.

I recommend the following which will achieve the field names as you desire using the struct tags recommended by Gorm:

```golang
type UserModel struct {
    FirstName string `gorm:"column:first_name"`
    LastName string `gorm:"column:last_name"`
}
```

See https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Conventions for more information.

Comment: Is there any way we define the name of the table when do function `CreateTable` ??

Comment: @ChauLoi yes. You need to read the docs. https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#TableName